# iOS Swift: How to prepare a cell for reuse

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UITableView with a custom cell, each of which contains a horizontally scrolling UICollectionView. When the table view cells are recycled the horizontal scroll position of the collection view is recycled with it. Should I be resetting the collection view scroll position manually when I create new cells? And if so is there a way to preserve the scroll position on a per-cell basis?

**Custom UITableViewCell**

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var collectionView:UICollectionView!
    var layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    var collectionData = [UIImage]()
    let kCellIdentifier = "Cell"

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.registerClass(ItemCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: kCellIdentifier)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: bounds.height)
        collectionView.frame = bounds
    }
}

extension ProjectCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(kCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemCell
        //Reset collectionView scroll position?
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to put the code to reset the scroll position in the `UICollectionViewCell` would be in the `prepareForReuse` method. Override it in your cell subclass and it will be called every time a previously existing cell is dequeued by `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`.

Comment: Is there any way to remember the scroll position for each cell? So when I scroll back to a cell I had interacted with previously it will be in the same scroll position?

Comment: You'll have to store the scroll position on the table view controller, and apply it when you provide the table view with a cell.

Comment: Can I store that value in the cell or do I need to store it in the view controller?

Comment: Store it in the view controller.

Comment: Hm. Having trouble with this. Should I create an array in the viewController that stores all of the scroll positions? And if so, what method do I use to save the scrollPosition into the array?

Comment: You need a way to grab the scroll position from a cell when it is done being displayed. A good way to do this is to implement the `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method. It will be called when a cell is about to go back into the reuse pool so you can save any information about it that you want before that happens. And yes, I would save the scroll positions either in an array or a dictionary.